# response.getReturnValue() as NaN from server controller response

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am getting a NaN value for response.getReturnValue() and data is not being stored. What exactly I need to do to identify an error message

**This is my controller**

```
({
doSubmit : function(cmp, evt, hlpr) {

    var regForm=cmp.get("v.RegForm_DB");

    var action=cmp.get("c.Save_Reg_Details");
    action.setParams({RegForm_DB: regForm});

    //Create a call back that is executed after
    //server side action returns
    action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        var state=response.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS"){
            //Alert the user with value
            //returned from the user
            alert("From server: ",response.getReturnValue());
            console.info('response', response);
            console.log("From server: ",+response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if(state === "INCOMPLETE"){
            console.log("iNCOMPLETE message: ");
        }
            else if(state === "ERROR"){
                var errors=response.getError();
                if(errors){
                    if(errors[0] && errors[0].message){
                        console.log("Error message: ",+ errors[0].message);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);

}
```

This is my Apex Class

```
public class Save_Registration_Details {

@AuraEnabled
public static id Save_Reg_Details(learning123__Registration_Details__c RegForm_DB){
    //inserting DML Operation
   insert RegForm_DB;
    return RegForm_DB.id;
}
```

}

This is my Console Log (How and where to find an exact error in response)
[image]

This is my Component Class

```
<aura:component controller="Save_Registration_Details" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <!-- Defining Attributes -->
<aura:attribute name="abc" type="string" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="NameOfStudent" type="String" default="your name"/>
<aura:attribute name="NameOfFather" type="String" default="father name"/>
<aura:attribute name="ClassStudying" type="String[]" default="Select One,Jr KG,Sr KG,One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten"/>
<aura:attribute name="ClassResponse" type="String" default="class name" />
<aura:attribute name="Section" type="String[]" default="A,B,C"/>
<aura:attribute name="SectionResponse" type="String" default="sec name" />
<aura:attribute name="PhoneNumber" type="integer" default="0"/>
<aura:attribute name="NoOfHoursStudy" type="String[]" default=",Less than 2 Hour,In Between 2 to 4 Hours,In Between 4 to 8 Hours,In Between 8 to 10 Hours,10 + Hours"/>
<aura:attribute name="HourResponse" type="String" default="study hrs" />
<aura:attribute name="HaveYouTakenClass" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="AreYouInterestedInOnline" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="EducationDetailsList" type="List" default="[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="RegForm_DB" type="learning123__Registration_Details__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'learning123__Registration_Details__c'}" />
<!--Attributes defining is done -->

<!--U/I Starts here  -->
<br/><br/> 
<div class="slds-size_3-of-8">
 <p>
<lightning:input  label="Enter your name" name="studentname" value="{!v.RegForm_DB.Name}" />
```

```
<lightning:select label="Which class you are studying?" name="ClsStudying" value="{!v.RegForm_DB.learning123__Class_Studying__c}">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.ClassStudying}" var="cls">
   <option value="{!cls}" text="{!cls}" />
    </aura:iteration> 
</lightning:select>

<lightning:select label="Please select your section?" name="SecResponse" value="{!v.RegForm_DB.learning123__Section__c}">
<aura:iteration items="{!v.Section}" var="sec">
    <option value="{!sec}" text="{!sec}" />
    </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>

    <lightning:select label="How many hours you want to study?" name="hrsStudy" value="{!v.RegForm_DB.learning123__Hours_Study__c}">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.NoOfHoursStudy}" var="hrs">
        <option value="{!hrs}" text="{!hrs}" />
 </aura:iteration>
</lightning:select>

<lightning:input type="telephone" label="Enter your telephone number" value="{!v.RegForm_DB.learning123__Mobile_Number__c}" />

     <br/>
```

```
     <lightning:button iconName="utility:add" label="Add Educational Details" onclick="{!c.addDetails}"/>


<lightning:input aura:id="checkCrs" label="Are you intrested Online?" type="checkbox" name="crsCheck" 
                 onchange="{!c.onCheckBox}"  />


        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.AreYouInterestedInOnline}" >
Have a great learning!
</aura:if>
    <br/>
     <lightning:button label="Submit" onclick="{!c.doSubmit}"/>

</div>
```

This is my Registration_Detail Object and the field relationships

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are't getting back `NaN`, which would be quite odd. Your server controller method will either return an `Id` or throw an exception.

You have a couple of bugs in your JavaScript.

```
        alert("From server: ",response.getReturnValue());
        console.info('response', response);
        console.log("From server: ",+response.getReturnValue());
```

`alert()` does not take two parameters, so `response.getReturnValue()` is never shown to you.

Your `console.log()` statement has either a spurious comma or a spurious plus (you need to pick one or the other). This results in `response.getReturnValue()` being interpreted in a numeric sense, but it's not a number.

You can illustrate this yourself by doing

```
console.log('Test', +'blah');
```

in a JavaScript console. You'll get back

> Test NaN

The fact that your `console.log()` messages are showing at all implies your server controller method is succeeding, since those messages are logged in the `'SUCCESS'` branch of your logic.

Comment: Thanks, David! I am able to see a record with the response code. I have removed all the bugs which you have mentioned